# Would I expose myself to liability by verbally abusing a debt collector?

Tags: united-states, civil-law, harassment, collections

I recently started receiving calls from a debt collector about a debt that I disputed and refused to pay 13 years ago. All the other debt collectors gave up around 10 years ago.

They told me right up front that they do not intend to sue me or put anything on my credit report. Besides, they don't know where I live or work. However, they insist that they will keep calling unless I send them a cease and desist letter. I'm not going to do that because I feel like messing with them and wasting their time. As long as they're talking to me, they're not talking to someone else in a weaker position. Of course, that's just a rationalization. It's really for my own personal amusement.

**Would I expose myself to any liability by verbally abusing them?** I know, anyone can sue you for anything. But I'm not going to make any threats, and sexual harassment is off the table. I'll ask them to call me on my lunch break so I can chew and belch into the phone. I plan to make small talk interspersed with questions like whether they've ever had a real job, how their parents feel about raising a failure, etc. My ultimate goal is to make them angry enough to violate the FDCPA, or upset them enough to quit their job.

Comment: The examples you describe (e.g. "make small talk interspersed with questions like whether they've ever had a real job" are not abuse.

Comment: It won't work. They've been called worse things than that by better people than you, and they also know how to play the game a lot better than you.

Comment: @PaulJohnson They keep calling, I win; they stop calling, I win. They saw the light and stopped calling.